# How to insert a image created by decode of a string to a pdf in pdfbox

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I'm trying to insert an image (which needs to be converted from a string by java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageInputString)) to a certain position of a pdf file.

The main logic of the code will be:

```
  //create a PDImageXObject myImage first (or something that could be used in addImage method. 
  //And this is what I could not figure out how to accomplish.

  //open the pdf file and use addImage to insert the image to the specific page at specific position.
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);  
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pageNumber);
  contentStream.addImage(myImage,x,y);
  document.save();
```

Most of the tutorial I found created the myImage from reading an image file. Could someone help me to see if I could do the same thing but with a byte [], which is the output of  java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageInputString)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()` ?

Comment: Your code is missing several lines that are important, please see in the source code download in the examples subproject, e.g. the `ImageToPDF.java` example.

Comment: Tilman Hausherr:  PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()  is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help. Could you please write an answer so that I could vote? I will post my final code after your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static method `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()`, which detects the file type based on contents and will decide which PDF image type / image compression is best. ([javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromByteArray-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-byte:A-java.lang.String-))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tilman Hausherr.
Here is the final code (just the core part):

```
int pageNumber = j;
PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber);
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
byte[] ba = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64str);
PDImageXObject sigimg = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(document,ba,"signature");
float imgW = sigimg.getWidth();
float imgH = sigimg.getHeight();
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true,true);
PDRectangle sigRect = field.getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
float fieldW = sigRect.getWidth();
float fieldH = sigRect.getHeight();
if (imgW > fieldW || imgH > fieldH){
        if(imgW/fieldW > imgH/fieldH){
                sigimg.setWidth(Math.round(fieldW));
                sigimg.setHeight(Math.round(imgH/imgW*fieldW));
        }
        else{
                sigimg.setWidth(Math.round(imgW/imgH*fieldH));
                sigimg.setHeight(Math.round(fieldH));
        }
}
contentStream.drawImage(sigimg,sigRect.getLowerLeftX(),sigRect.getLowerLeftY());
contentStream.close();
```